# Using traversal by pointer to check whether a string is repeated

Tags: c++, pointers

```
bool repeat_char(char *s, int n);
//R: s is a C-string of at least n non-NUL characters and n > 0
//E: returns true if the first n characters are fully repeated throughout the string s, false
//   otherwise.
```

I'm having trouble implementing this function using traversal by pointer.  I was thinking that I could extract the first n characters from s, then use that in a comparison with s, but I'm not sure how I could do that.  If I'm traversing through s one character at a time, how can I check that it matches a block of text, such as the first n characters of s?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can really only compare the characters one at a time, so you start at `s` and `s+n`, and compare a character. If they match, you compare the character at `s+1` to `s+n+1`. If they matching, go to `s+2`, and so on up to `n`. If they match up to that point, repeat starting from s+n*2, then s+n*3, etc., until you reach the end of the string.

If you find a mismatch, or reach the end of the string anywhere except matching the last character of the sub-string, then you return false. Otherwise, you return true.

Comment: What about in the case where we have "hellohellohellohello", 5? So that hello is repeated more than once?

Comment: @BobJohn: At least based on what you've said, it's irrelevant -- you just need to return true if there's at least one match, right? If so, the fact that there might be more matches later in the string is irrelevant.

Comment: I think you misunderstood.  The sub-string must be fully repeated throughout the entire string.  So, in the example I gave, if the last "o" were changed to a "t," the function should return false.

Comment: Yes, I did misunderstand. Editing answer.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative method (not quite traversal by pointer):

```
bool repeatOfFirstChars(int n, const char *s)
{
  len = strlen(s);

  if (len % n != 0) return false;

  for (int step = 1; step < len / n; step++) {
    if (0 != strncmp(s, s+n*step, n)) return false;
  }

  return true;
}
```